# merging two tables and adding additional column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using sql-server. I have two tables (simple snap shot below).

```
 table hlds                table bench
 name  country  wgt        name  country  wgt
 abc   us       30         abc   us       40
 mno   uk       50         ppp   fr       45
 xyz   us       20         xyz   us       15
```

what I would like to do is calculate the differnces in the wgt columns and insert the results into another table, lets call it merge_tbl. The other thing I would like to do is in merge_tbl have a bit column where it is 1 if the company exists in the table hlds.

So I would like the result to look like below,

```
 merge_tbl
 name  country  wgt  inHld
 abc   us       -10  1
 mno   uk       50   1
 xzy   us       5    1
 ppp   fr       -45  0
```

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a `FULL OUTER JOIN` to get records from both tables. Then, you can use a `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement to do the insert:

```
INSERT INTO merge_tbl
SELECT COALESCE(h.name, b.name) AS name, 
       COALESCE(h.country, b.country) AS country, 
       COALESCE(h.wgt, 0) - COALESCE(b.wgt, 0) AS wgt,
       CASE WHEN h.name IS NOT NULL THEN 1
            ELSE 0
       END AS inHld
FROM hlds AS h
FULL OUTER JOIN bench AS b ON h.name = b.name AND h.country = b.country
```

The `ON` clause of the `JOIN` operation depends on your actual requirements. I have made the assumption that records from `hlds`, `bench` tables match if *both* `name` and `country` fields are equal.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6f23b/1)